# Foreach in foreach (nested)

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to loop all disabled users through an array of groups to check if the users have membership in any of the listed groups. My thought is that for every user in the list loop them through and check if they are present in one of the listed groups. That would require nesting `foreach` loops, right? The output I get is like this:

```
...
user1
user2
user3

is not a member of group1
```

Here is the source code:

```
$dUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $false} |
          FT samAccountName |
          Out-String
$groups = 'Group1', 'Group2'

foreach ($dUser in $dUsers) {
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive |
                   Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

        if ($members -contains $dUsers) {
            Write-Host "[+] $dUser is a member of $group"
        } else {
            Write-Host "[-] $dUser is not a member of $group"
        }
    }
}
```

I'm pulling my hair because I feel like there is a simple solution, but I'm lost.

---

**Update:**

I wanted to put all disabled users in variable `$dUsers`.
It actually works if I manually put users in the variable like this:

```
$dUsers = 'user1','user2','user3'
```

Which gives me the following output:

```
user1 is not a member of group1
user1 is not a member of group2
user2 is not a member of group1
user2 is not a member of group2
...
```

This makes me question how it gets "foreached" when the variable is:

```
$dUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $false} |
          FT samAccountName |
          Out-String
```

Anyone got a clarification on that?

---

**Update:**

This is the final code. It takes a long time to run, even with only two groups.

```
$dUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $false} | Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName
$groups = 'Group1', 'Group2'


Write-host '[+] Checking if any disabled user is member of any SSL groups'
Write-host '[+] This might take a while. Get a coffee!'
write-host '[+] Running...'`n
foreach ($dUser in $dUsers) {
    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Recursive | Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName

        if($members -contains $dUser) {
            Write-Host "$dUser is a member of $group"
        } Else {
         # Remove or comment out the line below to get a clutterfree list.
         # Write-Host "$dUser is not a member of $group"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as i recall, there is a `.MemberOf` property for every ADUser. why don't you just grab all the users and then check for membership in the groups in question?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not well versed in powershell. Would you be able to provide me with an example?

Comment: `FT samAccountName | Out-String` -> `Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName`; `$members -contains $dUsers` -> `$members -contains $dUser`

Comment: You are working on three problems at the same time.  One is how to write scripts in powershell. A second one is how to make productive use of Get-ADUser.  A third is figuring out what you want your output to look like.  For the code you have shown us,  it looks like you are doing a cartesian product of users and groups.  If you have 200 users, and 10 groups, your output will be 2000 lines long.  Is that really what you want?

Comment: Of course, that's only disabled users, so maybe your numbers are smaller.

Comment: @xrefor - start with ONE thing. [*grin*] [1] get the list of disabled users. [2] look at one of the objects with `Get-Member` to see what is in the object. [3] according to the docs, the `.MemberOf` property is not automatically returned, so you will need to specify it with something like this `Get-ADUser -Identity $Username -Properties MemberOf` when addressing one user. [4] test to see if the groups you are interested in are listed in the `.MemberOf` property list. ///// i cannot test this since i have no AD access, but the MSDocs site covers the topic fairly well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two issues in your code:

1. You're creating a single string from the `Get-ADUser` output. Piping the output of that cmdlet through `Format-Table` (alias `ft`) and then `Out-String` creates one string with a tabular display of all matching account names including the table header.

   If you output `$dUsers` in a way that makes beginning and end of a string visible you'd see something like this (the leading and trailing `==` marking the beginning and end):

   ```
   PS> $dUsers | ForEach-Object { "==$_==" }
   ==samAccountName
   --------------
   user1
   user2
   user3==
   ```

   Since there is no account with a username matching this string no match can be found in any group and you're getting the output you observed.

   This misuse of `Format-*` cmdlets is a common beginner's mistake. People get a nicely formatted string output and then try to work with that. ONLY use `Format-*` cmdlets when you're presenting data directly to a user, NEVER when further processing of the data is required or intended.

   What you actually want is not a string with a tabular display of usernames, but an array of username strings. You get that by expanding the `SamAccountName` property of the user objects you get from `Get-ADUser`.

   ```
   $dUsers = Get-ADUser ... | Select-Object -Expand SamAccountName
   ```
2. The second issue is probably just a typo. Your condition `$members -contains $dUsers` won't work, since both `$members` and `$dUsers` are arrays (after fixing the first issue, that is). The `-contains` operator expects an array as the first operand and a single value as the second operand.

   Change

   ```
   $members -contains $dUsers
   ```

   to

   ```
   $members -contains $dUser
   ```

Comment: Thank you. This gave me the clarification I needed and I chose to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what PowerShell version you are on, there is a cmdlet for this use case and others.

As for

> I'm Trying to loop all disabled users

Just do...

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled | 
Select-Object -Property Name, Enabled,
@{Name = 'GroupName';Expression = {$_.DistinguishedName.Split(',')[1] -replace 'CN='}} 

# Results 

Name               Enabled GroupName                                              
----               ------- ---------                                              
...                                         
testuser2 NewTest    False Users                                                  
Guest                False Users
```

Or different cmdlet…

```
# Get disabled users and their group membership, display user and group name
ForEach ($TargetUser in (Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false}))
 {
 "`n" + "-"*12 + " Showing group membership for " + $TargetUser.SamAccountName
 Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $TargetUser.SamAccountName | Select Name
 }


# Results
...
------------ Showing group membership for testuser1
Domain Users
Users

------------ Showing group membership for testuser2
Domain Users
```

As for ...

> an array of Groups

Just select or filter the DN for the group name you want using the normal comparison operators.

As for...

> Unfortunately I'm not well versed in powershell.

… be sure to spend the necessary time to get ramped up on it, to limit the amount of misconceptions, confusions, errors, etc. that you are going to encounter. There are plenty of no cost / free video and text-based training / presentations all over the web.

Example:
[Videos](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell)

Use tools that will write the code for you that you can later tweak as needed.

[Step-By-Step: Utilizing PowerShell History Viewer in Windows Server 2012 R2](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/canitpro/2015/03/04/step-by-step-utilizing-powershell-history-viewer-in-windows-server-2012-r2)

[Learning PowerShell with Active Directory Administrative Center (PowerShell History Viewer)](https://sid-500.com/2017/10/10/learning-powershell-with-active-directory-administrative-center-powershell-history-viewer)

As well as plenty of sample scripts and modules via the [MS PowerShell Script / Module Gallery.](https://www.powershellgallery.com/)

Comment: Thank you for a well formed reply and the learning resources provided.

Comment: In your first example `GroupName` would actually be the OU and not a group he belongs to.

Comment: True, but that can be filtered out easily using the normal conventions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two commands for the AD Groups.
First I see that you want the membership of the disabled users that is easy.

```
#Get the dissabled users from your AD with all their attributes (properties and select)
$dUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {Enabled -eq $false} -Properties * | Select *
#Run a loop for each user to get the group membership
Foreach ($User in $dUsers) {
$User = $User.SamAccountName
Get-ADUser $User -Properties * | Select Name, SamAccountName, MemberOf | Format-Table -Wrap # > "D:\test\$user.txt" -HideTableHeaders
}
```

This one can work but I don't like the output that we get.
I prefer to run the groupmembership command and check the users.

```
$GroupMembers = Get-ADGroupMember "groupname"| Select Name, SamAccountName
ForEach ($User in $GroupMembers)
{ 
$UserProperties = Get-ADUser $User.SamAccountName -Properties * | select *
If ($UserProperties.Enabled -eq $False) {
Write-Host $UserProperties.SamAccountName
}
}
```

Edit:

Let me know if those fits you.
Kind regards.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually I need to check if all disabled users are member of several groups. The array will eventually contain a lot of groups.

How would I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know what kind of export you want to see.

Comment: Hi, In the export I just want a list of the users that is member of any of the groups.

To give it some context we have many disabled users that still is member of one or several VPN groups. We need an overview of the users that is member of any of the VPN groups so that we can remove them, thus clearing up number of assigned licenses so that we can assign them to new users.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should try to check is whenever you are only interested in direct memberships or indirect ones as well. Depending on the answer the options you got availabel change a bit. You probably will encounter [Distinguished Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/aa366101) while working on this so check out what they are if you don't know (mostly a path for an object).

If it's only direct memberships using `memberOf` with [`Get-ADUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/addsadministration/get-aduser?view=win10-ps) should be sufficient. The `memberOf` attribute contains every direct group membership of the user with the full Distinguished Name of the group.

```
Get-ADUser test -Properties MemberOf | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberOf
```

You can match the groups you're looking for in various ways. You could get the whole Distinguished Name of those groups or you could do a partial match. It's up to you to decide how to proceed.

If you need the indirect memberships as well you might want to split up your code to make it easier for yourself. For instance you could first find the users and save them. Afterwards find all group members of those groups (You already got that with `Get-ADGroupMember`) and finally compare the two.

Currently for every user you build the whole list of group members again. This approach would save a few resources as you wouldn't be doing the same queries over and over again.

Finally you could also use the `MemberOf` approach but get the list of every direct and indirect membership of a user using an LDAP query.

```
$dn = (Get-ADUser example).DistinguishedName
$userGroups = Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter ("(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:={0})" -f $dn)
```

This approach uses a [LDAP search query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/adsi/search-filter-syntax). It can be quite complex, you could also only check for one one of the groups by modifying it a bit.

In the end even your current approach should work. The problem is that you're comparing the AD object against the list of SAM Accountnames. You would need to check for the SAM Accountnames as well.

```
if($members -contains $dUsers.SamAccountName)
if($members -contains $dUsers | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName)
```

One of these should work if you change your `$dUsers` as well. As it currently is you end up with a giant string. You probably can check that by checking `$dUsers.length`. Just drop the `Format-Table` and `Out-String`.

Comment: thank you for an informative reply. I just need to check if the users assigned to the $dUsers variable is member of any one group in the $groups variable and then print out if it is or not. I was excited to see the different if-statements provided. Unfortunately it didn't change much as for the output.

Comment: Did change the `$dUsers` to be just `$dUsers = Get-ADUser -Filter {enabled -eq $false}`?